# Random123 error using fujitsu compiler

Tags: c++, sparc, softune

I am trying to build an application which resulted in the following error during make process

```
../../src/Random123/features/sse.h", line 275: warning: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)
R123_STATIC_INLINE int haveAESNI(){
^
"../../src/Random123/features/sse.h", line 275: error: expected a ";"
R123_STATIC_INLINE int haveAESNI(){
                   ^
```

The above code works fine with gnu compiler. I am trying with fujitsu compiler (using mpifccpx). Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does `R123_STATIC_INLINE` expand into?

Comment: Thanks. I found the issue. It expanded into static __inline_ and I made it static __inline and it worked.